# How to re enable (or rearm) Firefox Start Page flame

Tags: firefox

Most of us had noticed a flame on Firefox Start Page for a last few days (may be at the time of Olympics) like the image below;
[image: Olympic Flame Start Page]

But for some days, The flame is gone and is replaced with Firefox's default start page with Firefox logo like the screenshot below;
[image: Default Start Page]

Is there any way to enable (or rearm) the flame again? For sake, I saved the web page having the flame and is working fine.

*Note: It will be fine if there is a solution for those who don't have the backup file also.*

Answer (score 0):

That torch, was just for the olympics.

If you saved the page you may simply put it somewhere on the disk(hidden preferentially), copy the adress file://path/to/.html, and set as home page.

Comment: is there any way to do the same for those who don't have the backup?

Comment: After 10 minutes searching google, i found noting but complains(that the torch slows computer), a man trying to steal the torch and printscreens.
Sorry, if as you said, you saved the page, you may upload it to somewhere so other users can also have it.